# what does it mean if my macbook loaded in safe mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, startup, error

My MacBook just booted in safe mode. Is it possible that somehow I made it to do so, or can it automatically load in case of a malfunctioning? What does it mean if it did so automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you have hold down the shift key during startup it can go to safe mode. 
Sometime due to disk issue and new software installation it may go to safe mode.
Try restarting normally and it should be back to normal mode. If you have installed anything new try removing them in safe mode.

Comment: +10 on this one, almost a clean one, while a doubt remains what could have triggered it?

Comment: Would not hurt to recommend to repair the permissions using the Disk Utility just in case :)

Comment: So is it possible that the computer identified something malfunctioning and entered safe mode on its on?

Comment: Ya can be. That's why as a precaution as Buscar mentioned, open disk utility and click the repair button to make sure things are in place.